# message about missing apk in eclipse but runs fine

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

I've got an Eclipse project called MyAndroidProject.

I removed C2DM from it and replaced it with GCM.

Per instructions I read about how to do this, I created a google-play-services_lib project from android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib

Everything builds fine.  Everything runs fine.

When I run via eclipse, I see a message:

[2015-07-27 14:04:10 - google-play-services_lib] Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk!

I don't understand why.  Is this some kind of strange Eclipse thing?

When I right click on MyAndroidProject and pick Properties | Android I
see google-play-services_lib as a referenced project.

Its also defined as a project on the Build Path.

google-play-services.jar has been added as a jar files on the
Libraries tab and the jar is being exported in the "Order and Export"
tab.

The google-play-services_lib project is not being exported on "Order and Export"

I'm assuming this isn't a problem because the MyAndroidProject exports
to an apk that does run.  I do not see the message in log cat when I install the apk with

adb -r install

on a device.

I do see meesages in logcat that indicate GCM is being accessed.

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: Move to Android Studio already. ADT is deprecated.

Comment: this was my last project on Eclipse.  i wasn't particularly a fan.  it worked.  i used it.  it beat a text editor and the command line.